# How do I write a simple chat server in Perl using Net::Server?

Tags: perl

I want to write a [Net::Server](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Server) chat server, probably using PreFork, with process tied to an active client.  How do I "talk" between clients, with the proper filtering?

Comment: shuodl i also consdier using POE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start by taking a look at the [chat example bundled with Net::Server](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RHANDOM/Net-Server-0.97/examples/samplechat.pl).